# Display Department and Department SP Site URL in SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Im new to SharePoint but ive trying to create a new intranet homepage, where under a section i can pull information about the user who is currently viewing the page and then display the team SP site they below to.

For E.g
User A is part of IT department
User B is part of HR
Both of these users have their own team SP site

When these users visit the new SP intranet site, user A should have section that says:
IT Department
Your Team Site: URL of team site

for user B same as above but the URL for team site be HR one.

Is there any way to do this? Ive added Modern Script Editor web part to my SP sites so im able to present a welcome to  screen so far. i looked at Office365Users.MyProfileV2().department which outputs the department in PowerApp but im kind of stuck at that point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.